# Что делать после переустановки Git?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

ssh-Ключ по-новому нужно будет привязывать? Алиасы тоже не сохранятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в линукс системах ssh ключи хранятся в  папке .ssh она не удаляется при удалении git и установки поэтому ssh ключи переустанавливать не нужно 
а вот .git/config возможно прийдется поправить